# laravel Autenticación no manda correo

Tags: php, laravel, login

Hola estoy tratando de hacer funcionar la herramienta >php artisan make:auth para poder mandar un correo a la cuenta del usuario cuando entre al formulario de olvidaste tu contraseña

ya configure que fuesen correctas mis credenciales de server /host y proveedor de correo en .env 
y tengo mis controladores:
*ForgotPasswordController

LoginController

RegisterController

ResetPasswordController

VerificationController*

al subir mi proyecto a un host no tengo acceso a consola asi que simplemente e tratado de crear manual mente las tablas en myphpadmin y subir los documentos por filezilla (lo que me dio problemas pero ya lo solucione)

pero ahora al colocar el correo del usuario que quiere recuperar su contraseña sale el mensaje de "correo mandado correctamente" pero no manda el correo

alguien a tenido este problema?, no me sale error y no entiendo muy bien quienes están involucrados para transferir el correo

*nota: artisan crea/modifica muchos documentos automáticamente si hace faltas mostrar alguno pueden mencionarlo y adito con el codigo directamente*

Comment: De forma local si te envía el correo?

Comment: no, enrealidad estoy tratando de que funcione de manera local, pero solo dice que si loa anviado

Comment: coloca la configuración de tu `.env`, hay varias formas de configurar el envío de correos. (dejando oculta la información sensible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que te hace falta investigar bastante acerca del framework y del desarrollo web en general, iré por partes:

**1-** El comando `php artisan make:auth` crea una serie de archivos relacionados con la autenticación para que puedas tener todo hecho automáticamente al correr el comando, el comando se debe de correr en instalaciones nuevas de Laravel ya que si tienes archivos llamados de la misma forma en la que los añade, los sobreescribirá.
Estos archivos se encuentran en `resources/views/auth/`. Al igual que los controladores en `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/`. El comando **NO** envía ningún correo, lo que hace es dejar todo listo para cuando el usuario olvida la contraseña e ingresa su correo electrónico en el formulario, pero no es como que al correr el comando, se envíe el correo por sí solo.

**2-** Para que podamos apoyarte en la cuestión del correo, deberías de añadir en tu pregunta el código de la configuración en tu archivo `config/mail.php` y si usas variables de entorno (archivo `.env`) deberías de incluir sus valores (omitiendo credenciales si es que llegas a tener), al igual que deberías de mencionar como planeas enviar correos desde tu aplicación, ejemplo: smtp, mailgun, etc. De lo contrario, si no sabemos estos datos, no sabremos que es lo que esté pasando.

**3-** El hecho de no tener acceso a consola no debe de ser impedimento para ejecutar el proyecto, solo sería un obstáculo si tuvieras que instalar cosas con permisos de super usuario, pero seguro no es tu caso, entiendo que no puedas ejecutar comandos artisan cómodamente desde consola, pero para eso está la clase `Artisan`, la cual te permite ejecutarlos con código, ejemplos:

`Artisan::call('make:auth');`

`Artisan::call('make:controller', ['name' => 'TuControlador']);`, nótese en este caso recibe un parámetro extra el método `call` para poder asignarle un nombre al archivo que tratas de crear, puedes checar en la documentación oficial [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands).

**4-** Para la creación de tablas para eso existen las migraciones, ahora que ya sabes como ejecutar comandos `artisan` con código, puedes hacer lo siguiente para crear una tabla `blog` por ejemplo:

`Artisan::call('make:migration', ['name' => 'create_blog_table']);`

Una vez creadas tus migraciones puedes correr el comando `php artisan migrate` para que se añadan a tus tablas de la base de datos, más información, [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations).

En fin, me podría seguir y extenderme pero te recomiendo que leas la documentación de lo que necesitas

Comment: siempre paso mucho tiempo feente a la documentacion antes de preguntar xD aun que la verdad laravel aun me causa muchos problemas :( aun que es verdad lo que mencionas ya despues de desesperarme un poco reinicie un proyecto de cero con los cambios que agregue de otros puntos del proyecto y parece que ya funciona corectamente al migrar la carpeta y crear manual mente la tabla